# Search over all fields on Solr

Tags: search, solr

I'm trying to implement search over all fields on Solr. Ex`http://localhost:8983/solr/sample-items/select?q=oscar`
but no result returns. However, If I specify the field it works fine Ex `http://localhost:8983/solr/sample-items/select?q=name:oscar`

I try to use copyField like following but not working:
on managed-schema file

```
  <field name="Designation" type="text_general" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Location" type="text_general" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="age" type="plongs" stored="true"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="name" type="text_general" stored="true"/>
  <field 
    name="_text_" 
    type="text_general" 
    indexed="true" 
    stored="true" 
    multiValued="true"
  />
.
.
.

<fields>
  <copyField source="Designation" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="name" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="Location" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
</fields>
```

on solrconfig.xml
file

```
  <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
    </lst>

  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to search from >1 fields (or over all fields) by default , you need to perform following two configurations.

- In schema file (e.g. `managed_schema`) create copy field and copy other field's data into this copy field. Example is as follows.

`...
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
...
<copyField source="directed_by" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="genre" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
...`

- In `solrconfig.xml` , update `initiParam` tag to make above created copy field as default search field for search handlers. Example is as follows.

`<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>`

**Sample Query and output** :

`ShubhangiP:~ spardeshi$ curl -XGET http://localhost:8983/solr/films/select?q=Gary
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"Gary"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"/en/45_2006",
        "directed_by":["Gary Lennon"],
        "initial_release_date":"2006-11-30T00:00:00Z",
        "genre":["Black comedy",
          "Thriller",
          "Psychological thriller",
          "Indie film",
          "Action Film",
          "Crime Thriller",
          "Crime Fiction",
          "Drama"],
        "name":".45",
        "_version_":1645282402834055168}]
  }}`

From details provided in question, in `managed_schema` file collector field is used as copy field for three other fields named Designation , Name and Location.

But not sure  if you made collector field as default search field.

Comment: @IDI , Please note two things- 1) For above changes to work you need to restart Solr server 2) Only those documents which were indexed after above changes will be used for default query field (e.g. _text_).

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of using the edismax query parser. Here the link for the same. [the `edismax` query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) .Here you can provide the `qf` parameter. It provides you to boost hits in each field differently. For example `qf=field1^4 field2` will give hits in the `field1` field four times more weight than hits in the `field2` field.

Search across multiple fields, specifying (via boosts) how important each field is relative each other:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=video&defType=edismax&qf=features^20.0+text^0.3
```

You can boost results that have a field that matches a specific value:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=video&defType=edismax&qf=features^20.0+text^0.3&bq=cat:electronics^5.0
```